# Not being able to import a package to a worksheet in IntelliJ, scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

1. I create an empty package named `package1` in `main.scala` and add an `object dog` in it.
2. I open an empty worksheet in `main.scala` and type in `import package1.dog`
3. I execute the worksheet

I got following error:

> not found: value package1
>
> `import package1.dog`

package structure:
there are only 2 items:

- `main.scala.package1.dog`
- `main.scala.untitled.sc` (worksheet)

How can I correctly import the `object` in the package?

Comment: It's not clear: `main.scala` is a package or a file?

Comment: @GaëlJ `main` and `scala` are folders created automatically for Scala project. So package should be `package1` and object inside is `dog` and worksheet is not inside of any package. `scala` is source code root.

Comment: I'm not so sure from what OP describes..